# How do I fix mailcatcher 550 errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I'm running [mailcatcher](http://mailcatcher.me/) to see mail being sent via smtp on a Rails project, but on my machine when I go to send the email I'm getting:

```
Net::SMTPFatalError (550 Message rejected)
```

The message still shows up in mailcatcher, but it looks like the text is showing up as an attachment instead of as html.

If I run mailcatcher with verbose mode in the foreground `mailcatcher -f -v`, I get the following stack trace:

```
    Exception: undefined method `match' for nil:NilClass
    Backtrace:
       /Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@merchant_messaging/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/utilities.rb:104:in `unbracket'
       /Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@merchant_messaging/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/part.rb:29:in `cid'
       /Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@merchant_messaging/gems/mailcatcher-0.5.10/lib/mail_catcher/mail.rb:51:in `block in add_message'
       /Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@merchant_messaging/gems/mailcatcher-0.5.10/lib/mail_catcher/mail.rb:48:in `each'
       /Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@merchant_messaging/gems/mailcatcher-0.5.10/lib/mail_catcher/mail.rb:48:in `add_message'
       /Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@merchant_messaging/gems/mailcatcher-0.5.10/lib/mail_catcher/smtp.rb:45:in `receive_message'
       /Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@merchant_messaging/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/em/protocols/smtpserver.rb:532:in `process_data_line'
       /Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@merchant_messaging/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/em/protocols/smtpserver.rb:196:in `receive_line'
       /Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@merchant_messaging/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/em/protocols/linetext2.rb:64:in `receive_data'
       /Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@merchant_messaging/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/em/protocols/linetext2.rb:65:in `receive_data'
       /Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@merchant_messaging/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/em/protocols/linetext2.rb:65:in `receive_data'
       /Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@merchant_messaging/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/em/protocols/linetext2.rb:65:in `receive_data'
       /Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@merchant_messaging/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/em/protocols/linetext2.rb:65:in `receive_data'
       /Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@merchant_messaging/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
       /Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@merchant_messaging/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
       /Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@merchant_messaging/gems/mailcatcher-0.5.10/lib/mail_catcher.rb:134:in `run!'
       /Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@merchant_messaging/gems/mailcatcher-0.5.10/bin/mailcatcher:4:in `<top (required)>'
       /Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@merchant_messaging/bin/mailcatcher:19:in `load'
       /Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@merchant_messaging/bin/mailcatcher:19:in `<main>'
```

Apparently I'm not the only one with the issue.  See this github issue for more info https://github.com/sj26/mailcatcher/issues/73.

Comment: Any logs (var/logs/mail.log), or more verbose debugging logs?